# Get previous fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a Layout were i keep swapping my two Fragments **MainFragment and SecondFragment**
I have an Activity Level Button and with its onclick I swap these fragments in the layout.

But I need to keep the same instance of FragA every time I switch back from FragB.
Below is the code that i used but the application crashes with a NullPointerError.

```
// When journey button menu is clicked [INSIDE THE MAIN ACTIVITY]
    OnClickListener journeyBtnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentType==0){
                InitThisFragment(1);
            }else{
                InitThisFragment(0);
            }
        }
    };

    private int currentType=0;
    public void InitThisFragment(int type){
        if(type==0){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //get the previously added MainFragment from the BackStack
            Fragment mainFragment= getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main");
            transaction.replace(R.id.abs_fragment_container,mainFragment);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);
            transaction.commit();
        }else{
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.abs_fragment_container, new SecondFragment());
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        currentType=type;

    }
```

Before this I initialize the MainFragment in the OnCreate() of my Activity class;

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.abs_fragment_container, new MainFragment());
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN); //add MainFragment in the BackStack
            transaction.addToBackStack("main");
            transaction.commit();
}
```

I the user clicks the Button

- Initiate a New Fragment of the SecondFragment [No History of the
  Previous Fragment]
- Go Back to the MainFragment [In same state as it was while leaving
  it]

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you want to do, you can just call "FragmentManager.popBackStack()" if you are in the secondFragment.

So:

```
public void InitThisFragment(int type){
    if(type==0){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else{
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.abs_fragment_container, new SecondFragment());
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    currentType=type;

}
```

Comment: small issue; my application min sdk is 8. So getting an error!

Comment: So use getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

Answer (score 0):

Put "main" tag in replace method.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.abs_fragment_container, new MainFragment(),"main");
```

tag parameter would work different for addToBackStack and replace method. According to android for tag parameter :

[addToBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29): An optional name for this back stack state, or null.

[replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29): Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the fragment with `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String).`